# Nextjs/React/JS How compress video file uploaded by user through input (client side preferred)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ffmpeg, next.js, video-compression

I have made a basic app where the user can upload a video file through an input.
As you can see in the code i also retrieve the duration and the size of the initial video.

Now the question is, how i can compress the video file in the function "compressvid" so that the size of the video becomes massively smaller (at later stage i want to upload these videos to firebase firestore).
I'e read something about ffmpeg but wasn't able to figure out how to use it here.
I prefer it to be client side as the videos a client can upload are at max 30sec long.
If client side is not possible how would it work server side?

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export default function Home() {

  const [videofile, setVideo] = useState("")
  const [viddur, setviddur] = useState("")


  useEffect(() => {
    // only run this if videofile exists
    if (videofile != "") {
      console.log("compress video now ")
      console.log(videofile.type)


      // get duration of video by creating a theoretical video component
      var video = document.createElement('video');
      video.preload = 'metadata';
      video.onloadedmetadata = function() {
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(video.src);
        // here now can check if video is too long
        setviddur(video.duration)
      }
      video.src = URL.createObjectURL(videofile)
      
    }
  }, [videofile]);

  const clickedvideo = () => {
    console.log("clicked video")
  }

  const compressvid = () => {
    // here need to compress the video so that the size is smaller: preferred client-side; if that's not possible howis it posssible server side or with a cheap api
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>Video Compressor</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Video compressor" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main className={styles.main}>
        <h1 className={styles.title}>
          Video compressor
        </h1>
        <p>Size of video before: {videofile.size}</p>
        <p>Duration of video: {viddur}</p>
        <p>Size of video after: { }</p>
        <input className={styles.videoinput} id="myvideo" type="file" accept="video/mp4,video/x-m4v,video/*" onChange={(e) => setVideo(e.target.files[0])}></input>
        <div>
          {(videofile != "") ? <video autoPlay loop id="video" src={URL.createObjectURL(videofile)} onClick={clickedvideo} width="300px" height="300px" ></video> : null}
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I tried to compress a video uploaded by a user but didn't figure out how to solve it.

Comment: [ffmpeg wasm](https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/ffmpeg.wasm) would be a good place to start imo

Comment: @kesh also found that but there is no explanation on how to take a video and compress it, can't find anything

Comment: There are literally thousands of tutorials/example/etc. using FFmpeg to compress video. Googling "how to compress video with ffmpeg" should get you started.